# Setting FPS for Basler dart in pylon ARM build

Tags: c++, camera, odroid, basler

I'm trying to get to work with a Basler dart-3840 on an ODROID device.
I've installed the `pylon 7.3.0 Camera Software Suite Linux ARM 64 bit - Debian Installer Package`.

I can succesfully compile a project, request device information (like Serialnumber, device name etc) and capture images of the basler camera.

But I'm now trying to set the Framerate (and Height/Widht/OffsetX/OffsetY), but I'm running in some issues. As these values can't be found.

This was my first try:

```
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
int main( int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[] )
{
    PylonInitialize();
    CTlFactory& tlFactory = CTlFactory::GetInstance();
    CInstantCamera camera( tlFactory.CreateFirstDevice() );
    camera.AcquisitionFrameRateEnable.SetValue(true);
    camera.AcquisitionFrameRate.SetValue(30.0);
}
```

But this gives the compiler errors:

```
error: 'class Pylon::CInstantCamera' has no member named 'AcquisitionFrameRateEnable'
error: 'class Pylon::CInstantCamera' has no member named 'AcquisitionFrameRate'
```

I've also tried to change these parameters using a nodemap:
This was my first try:

```
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
int main( int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[] )
{    PylonInitialize();
     CTlFactory& tlFactory = CTlFactory::GetInstance();
     CInstantCamera camera( tlFactory.CreateFirstDevice() );
     INodeMap& nodemap = camera.GetNodeMap();
     CFloatParameter acquisitionFrameRate(nodemap, "AcquisitionFrameRate");
     acquisitionFrameRate.SetValue(30.0);
}
```

But this gives a runtime `Node is not writable.` exception

Finally I've tried searching the libraries for `AcquisitionFrameRate` and found out that it is found in the `_BaslerUsbCameraParams.h`

So my last try was to add a `CBaslerUsbInstantCamera` to change the `AcquisitionFrameRate`

```
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
#include <pylon/usb/PylonUsbIncludes.h>
int main( int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[] )
{
    PylonInitialize();
    CTlFactory& tlFactory = CTlFactory::GetInstance();
    CInstantCamera camera( tlFactory.CreateFirstDevice() );
    CBaslerUsbInstantCamera* usbCamera = (CBaslerUsbInstantCamera*)&camera;
    usbCamera->AcquisitionFrameRateEnable = true;
    usbCamera->AcquisitionFrameRate = 30;
}
```

But this gave a runtime `Segmentation Fault` crash on the setting of the `AcquisitionFrameRateEnable`

Hopefully somebody can inform me what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm using:

```
Device: ODroid, arm
IDE: VSCode - Remote debugging over SSH
Compiling: CMake (I can add CMakeLists.txt when needed)
Pylon 7.3.0 Camera Software Suite Linux ARM 64 bit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rubber duck debugging did it's work.

The issue is resolved by directly creating an `CBaslerUsbInstantCamera` and first opening the camera before trying to change the parameters.

```
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
#include <pylon/usb/PylonUsbIncludes.h>
int main( int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[] )
{
    PylonInitialize();
    CTlFactory& tlFactory = CTlFactory::GetInstance();
    CBaslerUsbInstantCamera camera( tlFactory.CreateFirstDevice() );   //Create CBaslerUsbInstantCamera instead of CInstantCamera 
    camera.Open();  //Open camera before changing parameters
    usbCamera.AcquisitionFrameRateEnable = true;
    usbCamera.AcquisitionFrameRate = 30;
}
```

The nodemap way does also work using the CBaslerUsbInstantCamera and Opening the camera

```
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
#include <pylon/usb/PylonUsbIncludes.h>
int main( int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[] )
{
    PylonInitialize();
    CTlFactory& tlFactory = CTlFactory::GetInstance();
    CBaslerUsbInstantCamera camera( tlFactory.CreateFirstDevice() );   //Create CBaslerUsbInstantCamera instead of CInstantCamera 
    camera.Open();  //Open camera before changing parameters

    CFloatParameter acquisitionFrameRate(nodemap, "AcquisitionFrameRate");
    acquisitionFrameRate.SetValue(30.0);
}
```